# How to get the pandas series diff in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeseries called ts, with some values as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


ts = pd.Series(range(10))
ts.index = pd.date_range('2019-01-01',periods=len(ts))
ts
```

I can get multiple differencing like this:

```
ts.diff().dropna()

ts.diff().diff().dropna()
```

How can I do this using for loop?

```
for d in range(7):
    tsx = ? # I dont know what to do here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `eval` function:

```py
for d in range(7):
    tsx = eval('ts' + '.diff()'*d + '.dropna()')
```

Answer (score 2):

We have `pd.eval`

```
for d in range(7):
    tsx = pd.eval('ts'+'.diff()'*d+'.dropna()')
```